# Is this a race condition in MediaPlayerService::Client::disconnect()?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

It seems like `mPlayer.clear()` should be called while `mLock` is held?

[platform/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerService.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerService.cpp)

```
void MediaPlayerService::Client::disconnect()
{
    ALOGV("disconnect(%d) from pid %d", mConnId, mPid);
    // grab local reference and clear main reference to prevent future
    // access to object
    sp<MediaPlayerBase> p;
    {
        Mutex::Autolock l(mLock);
        p = mPlayer;
        mClient.clear();
    }

    mPlayer.clear(); // <---- shouldn't this be moved above under the lock?

    // clear the notification to prevent callbacks to dead client
    // and reset the player. We assume the player will serialize
    // access to itself if necessary.
    if (p != 0) {
        p->setNotifyCallback(0, 0);
#if CALLBACK_ANTAGONIZER
        ALOGD("kill Antagonizer");
        mAntagonizer->kill();
#endif
        p->reset();
    }

    disconnectNativeWindow();

    IPCThreadState::self()->flushCommands();
}
```

Comment: Maybe @fadden knows for sure...

Comment: I don't know.  If think you've found a bug, file it on http://b.android.com/ .